# How to handle array from collection_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a form that uses collection_select to be able to select multiple groups. But when I try to create a new record it fails in my notifications_controller.rb. The parameters are being passed correctly I think it might have to do with collection_select being passed as an array. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to handle it in the controller.

```
 undefined method `users' for #<Array:0x007fbb0e891b58>
```

What is being passed in the parameters:

```
 "group"=>{"group_id"=>["1", "2"]},
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "title"
 t.string "first_name"


 end

create_table "notifications_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.bigint "user_id", null: false
 t.bigint "notification_id", null: false
 end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.string "user_type"
 t.string "username"


end
```

new.html.erb

```
   <%= f.label :To %>
       <%= collection_select(:group, :group_id, Group.all,:id,:name, 
        {include_hidden: false}, {:multiple => true})%>
```

notifications_controller.rb

```
def create

@notification = Notification.new(notification_params)


if @notification.save
  @group = Group.find(params[:group][:group_id])

  #raise @group.inspect

  @users = @group.users <--this is where it fails   
  @users.each do |user|
  @notification.users << user
end .....
```

Comment: Does your `Group` model contain a `has_many :users` association?

Comment: Yes, class Group < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
def create

  @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)

  if @notification.save
    @group = Group.where(id: params[:group][:group_id])

    @group.each do |group|
      @users = group.users <--this is where it fails   
      @users.each do |user|
      @notification.users << user
    end
  end
end
```

As you're selecting multiple groups and searching the group, you'll be getting an `Array` of the Groups. Instead when using the `where` as above, you'll get a `ActiveRecordRelation`

You've to loop through this result and use the `users` association with each record.

**Note**: The `associations` don't work with Active Record Relations or Arrays.

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: YES!!! thank you I have been struggling with this all day. What is that .where is it a method so I can look it up.

Comment: Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html. You can directly search for where as well. It is used for querying to obtain multiple records. Also, i would tell you to go ver the basic before moving forward. Glad i could be of help!